# How do I give all list items a max-width without having all of them fill that width

Tags: html, css

http://cdpn.io/gsDHK

Link to Codepen ^

I have a problem with this list. I need to break the words at a certain point on all of these, but I am unable to change the HTML within the list items.

I set a max-width of 72px on each list item. But Now they are all 72px wide. They should be auto width with a max width of 72px. The white space on either side of each list item has to be even. As you can see on the Learning Center link, there is more white space than on the others.

Comment: You items are 72px because they are forced to the max-width hence it is smaller than the natural width your li would take. Search for 'white-space', 'text-overflow' and 'word-wrap' to lurn about textual element behaviors.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the `text-align` property to `center`. This way you get even spacing on both sides.

Comment: Can't do that. They have to be left aligned. I don't think that would make them evenly spaced anyway.